Juniper QFX10002-36Q
We have a pair of QFX10002-36Q and we want to configure them as Virtual Chassis but it seems they do not support this, Is there any feature like as virtual chassis for them?

First result on google for it is the datasheet that says:

The QFX10002 switches are members of the QFX10000 line of Ethernet switches, which can be deployed in a number of different designs and fabrics for Layer 2 and Layer 3 networks, including multichassis link aggregation (MC-LAG), Junos Fusion, and EVPN/VXLAN-based configurations on IP fabric underlay.

That seems like what you want.
https://www.juniper.net/us/en/products/switches/qfx-series/qfx10002-fixed-ethernet-switches-datasheet.html

so it just supports MC-LAG and it does not support virtual chassis?

Virtual Chassis is not recommended for the QFX9200, Junos Fusion is recommended instead so I would assume the 10000 line is the same. https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/fusion-enterprise/topics/concept/junos-fusion-enterprise.html
https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/virtual-chassis-qfx/topics/concept/virtual-chassis-switches-overview.html

To confirm, the QFX10K does NOT support VC (or VCF). Additionally, I don't advise you to use Junos Fusion.

If you are familiar with Juniper EX Series switch Virtual Chassis configuration, the QFX Series requires different configuration generally will not auto-configure virtual chassis ports unless you are connecting to an existing provisioned virtual chassis.
To begin VCP port configuration use the following syntax from Setting an Uplink Port on an EX Series or QFX Series Switch as a Virtual Chassis Port:
 user@switch> request virtual-chassis vc-port set pic-slot 1 port 0

Other links that will be useful for yon configuring your QFX Virtual chassis are:

Understanding How the Primary in a Virtual Chassis Is Elected
QFX10002 Port Panels

